# custom mean and var for standard_scaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

How we can use `custom mean` and `var` in `standard_scaler`? I need to calculate mean and var for all data in the dataset (train set+test set) and then use these values to standardize the train set and test set (and later input data) separately. How can I do this?

I couldn't find any example of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

# Your training data
X_train = ...

# Your test data
X_test = ...

# Concatenate the training and test data
X_all = np.concatenate((X_train, X_test))

# Initialize the scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

# Fit the scaler on the combined data set
scaler.fit(X_all)

# Transform the training data
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)

# Transform the test data
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

If you want to use input data instead of traning set you could include this:

```
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=True, mean=mean_all, 
scale=var_all)
input_data = #input data
input_data_scaled = scaler.transform(input_data)
```

Comment: unfortunately i find this error:                                                                                    
  scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=True, mean=mean_all,scale=var_all)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mean'

Comment: Apologies, the code has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one is the best one!

I found that the normal StandardScaler is the best answer to my question.
StandardScaler(with_mean=False,with_std=False) that means mean=0 and var=1.
These values is fix for train set, test set and input data. so it's OK!